# integral of $x^2e^{-x^2}~dx$ from $-\infty$ to $+\infty$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, improper-integrals, exponentiation

I know that the

$$\int^{+\infty}_{-\infty}e^{-x^2}~dx$$ is equal to $\sqrt\pi$

It's also very clear that 
$$\int^{+\infty}_{-\infty}xe^{-x^2}~dx$$ is equal to 0;

However, I cannot manage to calculate this really similar integral.

$$\int^{+\infty}_{-\infty}x^2e^{-x^2}~dx$$

I know that the result is $\frac{\sqrt\pi}{2}$ but I don't know how to get to this result. I tried different substitution, but it doesn't seem to help. 
Any idea?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Try integration by parts.

Comment: $x^2e^{-x^2} = \frac x2\cdot 2xe^{-x^2}$

Comment: use parts,it is helpfull

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I'm surprised no one has given this answer.
We have of course by $u$-substitution
$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-\alpha x^2} dx = \sqrt{\frac{\pi}{\alpha}}.$$
Take a derivative of each side with respect to $\alpha$ to get
$$-\int_{-\infty}^\infty x^2 e^{-\alpha x^2} dx = -\frac{1}{2} \frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{\alpha^{3/2}}.$$
Substitute $\alpha = 1$ and cancel negative signs.

EDIT: I see that Felix Marin does essentially the same thing, but I think this is a better explanation.

Comment: This is really a beautiful answer indeed. Thank you.

Comment: I still remember the day when one of my classmates showed me this and told me he learned this particular trick from one of my favorite professors.

Answer (score 7):

$$\begin{align} \int_{-\infty}^\infty x^2e^{-x^2}\text dx&=2\int_0^\infty x^2e^{-x^2}\text dx\\
&=\int_0^\infty \sqrt ue^{-u}\text du\\
&=\Gamma\left(\frac32\right)\\
&=\frac12\Gamma\left(\frac12\right)\\
&=\frac12\int_0^\infty\frac{e^{-u}}{\sqrt u}\text du\\
&=\int_0^\infty e^{-x^2}\text dx\\
&=\frac{\sqrt \pi}2 \end{align}$$

Comment: Can you show how to get there without using the gamma function?

Comment: Is that more acceptable?

Answer (score 6):

$\newcommand{\+}{^{\dagger}}%
 \newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle #1 \right\rangle}%
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace #1 \right\rbrace}%
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack #1 \right\rbrack}%
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil #1 \right\rceil\,}%
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}%
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\equalby}[1]{{#1 \atop {= \atop \vphantom{\huge A}}}}%
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}%
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}%
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}%
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}%
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}%
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}%
 \newcommand{\isdiv}{\,\left.\right\vert\,}%
 \newcommand{\ket}[1]{\left\vert #1\right\rangle}%
 \newcommand{\ol}[1]{\overline{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left( #1 \right)}%
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}%
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,#2\,}\,}%
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}%
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}%
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}$

1. \begin{align}
   \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}x^{2}\expo{-x^{2}}\,\dd x
   &=\left.-\,\partiald{}{\mu}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\expo{-\mu x^{2}}\,\dd x
   \right\vert_{\,\mu\ =\ 1}
   =
   \left.-\,\partiald{}{\mu}\pars{\mu^{-1/2}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\expo{-x^{2}}\,\dd x}
   \right\vert_{\,\mu\ =\ 1}
   \\[3mm]&=
   \left.-\pars{-\,\half}\mu^{-3/2}\right\vert_{\,\mu\ =\ 1}\
   \underbrace{\quad\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\expo{-x^{2}}\,\dd x\quad}
   _{\ds{=\ \root{\pi}}}
   \end{align}
   $$\color{#0000ff}{\large%
   \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}x^{2}\expo{-x^{2}}\,\dd x = {\root{\pi} \over 2}}
   $$
2. \begin{align}
   \color{#0000ff}{\large\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}x^{2}\expo{-x^{2}}\,\dd x}
   &=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\pars{-\,\half}x\,\totald{\expo{-x^{2}}}{x}\,\dd x
   =\overbrace{\left.-\,\half\,x\expo{-x^{2}}\right\vert
   _{-\infty}^{\infty}}^{\ds{=\ 0}}
   +
   {1 \over 2}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\expo{-x^{2}}\,\dd x
   \\[3mm]&= \color{#0000ff}{\large{\root{\pi} \over 2}}
   \end{align}

Comment: I think the first line is missing an '=' sign, is that right? I was going to edit it myself until I saw your $L_AT_EX$ hell...

Comment: @TonyK I just added the $\large =$ sign. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

The standard solution requires a trick using polar coordinates. If the value of your $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}$ is $V$, then
$$
    V^{2} = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-x^{2}}e^{-y^{2}}dx dy = \int_{0}^{2\pi}\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-r^{2}}rdrd\theta=2\pi\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{r^{2}}rdr=\pi.
$$
So $V = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-x^{2}}dx=\sqrt{\pi}$. Integrating by parts finishes the problem as:
$$\begin{align}
   \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}x^{2}e^{-x^{2}}dx&=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}x\frac{d}{dx}\left[-\frac{1}{2}e^{-x^{2}}\right]dx = \left.x\left[-\frac{1}{2}e^{-x^{2}}\right]\right|_{-\infty}^{\infty}+\frac{1}{2}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-x^{2}}dx\\
    &= \frac{1}{2}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-x^{2}}dx=\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2}.\end{align}
$$

Comment: You integrated $e^{-x^2}$ he wants $x^2 e^{-x^2}$.

Comment: Read his full answer!

Answer (score 4):

Same trick as T.A.E. but without integrating by parts:
$$
\begin{align}
\left(\int_{-\infty}^\infty x^2\,e^{-x^2}\,\mathrm{d}x\right)^2
&=\int_{-\infty}^\infty\int_{-\infty}^\infty x^2y^2\,e^{-x^2}e^{-y^2}\,\mathrm{d}x\,\mathrm{d}y\\
&=\int_0^\infty\int_0^{2\pi}r^4\cos^2(\theta)\sin^2(\theta)\,e^{-r^2}\,r\,\mathrm{d}\theta\,\mathrm{d}r\\
&=\int_0^\infty r^4e^{-r^2}\,r\,\mathrm{d}r\int_0^{2\pi}\cos^2(\theta)\sin^2(\theta)\,\mathrm{d}\theta\\
&=\frac18\int_0^\infty s^2e^{-s}\,\mathrm{d}s\int_0^{2\pi}\sin^2(2\theta)\,\mathrm{d}\theta\\
&=\frac18\cdot2!\cdot\pi\\
&=\frac\pi4
\end{align}
$$
Therefore,
$$
\int_{-\infty}^\infty x^2\,e^{-x^2}\,\mathrm{d}x=\frac{\sqrt\pi}{2}
$$
One might use integration by parts to get $\int_0^\infty s^2e^{-s}\,\mathrm{d}s=2$ if one didn't recognize it as $2!$.

Answer (score 3):

For $n\geq 0$ let $A_n = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} x^{2n}e^{-x^2} dx$. Then

$$A_n =  \sqrt{\pi}\frac{{2n \choose n}n!}{4^n}.$$

Indeed, $$\sum_{n=0}^\infty A_n t^n/n! = \int_{-\infty}^\infty \sum_{n=0}^\infty e^{-x^2}(tx^2)^n dx/n! = \int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-x^2(1-t)}dx = \frac{\sqrt \pi}{\sqrt{1-t}}.$$

Comparing coefficients of $t$ on both sides we find the above formula (using the fact that $1/\sqrt{1-4t} = \sum_{n=0}^\infty {2n \choose n}t^n$).

Answer (score 1):

Given that you know $\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-x^2}dx=\sqrt{\pi}$:

First, we note it's easy to integrate $x e^{-x^2}$ ( by substitution $u=x^2$)   $$\int x e^{-x^2}dx= -\frac{1}{2}e^{-x^2}$$

Then, we can apply integration by parts:

$$\int x \,x e^{-x^2}\text dx= -\frac{x}{2}e^{-x^2} + \frac{1}{2}\int e^{-x^2}dx$$

Therefore

$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty x^2  e^{-x^2}\text dx=  -\frac{x}{2}e^{-x^2}\bigg|_{-\infty}^\infty+\frac{1}{2}\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-x^2}dx=0-0+\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{\pi}=\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2}$$